# Using Pdf.js in Android hybrid app to load local files

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, hybrid-mobile-app, pdf.js

I am developing an app for android using Sencha touch and Cordova which needs to load PDF files.I found the Child browser support on PDF is not there for Android.So I decided to use PDF.js.I am using the following line of code to open the PDF file :

```
window.open(\''+ ROOT_FOLDER+'/app/util/PDFJS/web/viewer.html?file='+ROOT_FOLDER + '<Path to PDF file>\'
```

`ROOT_FOLDER` is the local file path URL like `file://app/utils..`"

But the pdf is not loading in this case and it is throwing an exception like

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///android_asset/www/<path to PDF file>. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue, or how to load PDF files from local location using PDF.js

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load the files from local location, then it should be present in the **same folder** with viewer.html. In short the PDF should not be outside the main folder where all these html and js files are present.

Comment: What if it MUST be in different folders?

Comment: For that you should host your pdf in a local server using software like Xampp.

Comment: I would but the file needs to be downloaded from the server in order to run pdf.js. Also, can you elaborate as to why you should have both in the same folder?

Comment: Just the pdf I meant. I worked on some project related to pdf.js and it worked only when it was in same folder.

Comment: Interesting, I've been loading a pdf downloaded from a server to my cache then load that via pdf.js into an index.html which is loaded into a webview (which worked) but a slightly complicated approach so now im skipping out the download of the file part.